# Java play multimedia file from byte array

Tags: java, multimedia

I am developing a P2P streaming application.
There are many library for playing multimedia file, but I can't find the one that can play from **byte array**.
Is there any recommendation? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any media API worth using will accept an `InputStream`. A `byte[]` can be be turned into an `InputStream` as simply as [`new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream%28byte%5b%5d%29)

Comment: *"..suggesting an API .. There are many library for playing multimedia.."*  Link to the JavaDocs of these many libraries.  I'll have a look.  Would you mind spelling all the letters of words like 'you' and 'thanks'?

Comment: Ok. I have a look of "vlcj", it seems that it can only play file. And the official JMF is just useless because it only support old formats